# confusion about static int and calling them in printf

Tags: c, variables, static

Please test this code and give me your answers :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func() {
static int n = 0;
n++;
return n;
}

int main() {
    /*int first = func();
    int second = func();*/
    printf(" first call : %d \n second call : %d ",func(),func());
    return 0;
}
```

Logically it should print 1 and 2 but it is printing 2 and 1 .
If you Un-Comment the comments and print the variables "first" and "second" , the problem is solved!
What is happening?

thank you already!

Comment: A good rule of thumb in programming as in life - just do one thing at a time

Answer (score 6):

The order in which a function call's arguments are evaluated is unspecified, i.e., the compiler is free to make the two `func()` calls in any order before passing the return values to `printf`. If you first assign the results to variables, obviously you get to decide in which order they are used.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the parameters to a function are passed is not defined in the standard, and is determined by the calling convention used by the compiler. I think in your case, **cdecl** calling convention (which many C compilers use for x86 architecture) is used in which arguments in a function get evaluated from right to left.

Comment: downvoters doesn't explain + what you say is right => no more negative score at least

Comment: It is not right. Interestingly, this time the most upvoted answer is correct. You can easily verify in the C standard by reading 6.5.2.2. I suggest deleting this answer. Also, downvoting without providing an explanation should be prohibited.

Answer (score -1):

because while calling the function it takes right associative..
i.e, the last one in printf gets called first then the before one.. thats why it is printing 2 then 1.
try using two print statements like:
printf("First call: %d\n",func()); 
printf("second call: %d\n",func());

Comment: The order is unspecified in the C standard. It is true that on most common platforms and compilers today it is consistently right-to-left, but you can't rely on this behavior unless you are only writing for a specific compiler + platform, and it promises to stay consistent in this. (And even so, it would be bad style to do so.)